# Constrain Button with its own width

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

Really struggling to `constrain` my `buttons`.

All I want is do setup my 2 `buttons` to have a `height` of *35* and their `width` should be whatever they need. Right now it looks like this (left & right buttons):

[image]

This is how I set them up:

```
let communityButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill"), for: .normal)
    v.tintColor = UIColor.darkCustom
    v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(communityButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()

let profileButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.fill"), for: .normal)
    v.tintColor = UIColor.darkCustom
    v.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    v.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
    v.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

**Constraints:**

```
//contrain communityButton
communityButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.centerYAnchor),
communityButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.centerXAnchor, constant: -view.frame.width/3.5),
communityButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35),

// constrain profileButton
profileButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.centerYAnchor),
profileButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomBar.centerXAnchor, constant: view.frame.width/3.5),
profileButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35),
```

What is the right way to constrain here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to let autoLayout know that you want width to be flexible. You can do that by adding this line on both of your button definitions: -

```
// Replace "myButton" with your buttons name in your case "v"
 myButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth]
```

**Edits: -** 
Since you are using system images, if you want your button to look bigger then you have to increase the font size on your image configuration. Edit your images by adding configuration with your preferred font sizes.

For example: -

```
let communityButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
//----
// NB: - Change the font size for bigger icons and viceversa
let imageSymbolConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 50, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.3.fill", withConfiguration: imageSymbolConfiguration), for: .normal)

// -----

    return v
}()


let profileButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    // ----
// NB: - Change the font size for bigger icons and viceversa
let imageSymbolConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 50, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
v.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.fill", withConfiguration: imageSymbolConfiguration), for: .normal)
     // ----
    return v
}()
```

**Explanation:-**

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/symbolconfiguration)

"Symbol image configuration objects include details such as the point size, scale, text style, weight, and font to apply to your symbol image. The system uses these details to determine which variant of the image to use and how to scale or style the image."

Comment: that didn't anything :( do I have to change something else?

Comment: Hey, @Chris I edited my answer, please check it again.

Comment: that seems to be working! what exaclty is `pointSize` , `weight` & `scale`

Comment: I added explanations at the bottom of my answer.